# Do war hosts have any weaknesses?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

A massive army of 10000 men suddenly appeared, intent on conquering Sweden.

My own army itself is only 10000 including mercenaries, but even if I get good defensive ground they get wiped out immediately. My troops are already raised (due to other wars) and their morale is at maximum, but they still get trounced once the battle moves to melee range (I suspect the enemy has more heavy infantry).

Had this been a country, I could split my army and siege several different holdings simultaneously or something, but there seems to be no actual weaknesses in this bomb.

What are the ways I can resist an unbeatable army?

Comment: Are you attempting to fight them right after raising your 10,000, or are you waiting until your army's morale is full?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The morale is full, the troops were already raised for another war (or three). They're actually winning the the initial phases, but once they get into melee... I suspect the enemy has too much heavy infantry.

Comment: Have you tried getting your army out of the way and letting them siege a few holdings until they're somewhat depleted, then attacking them in strength?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No not yet. I thought I'd seek advice before committing to a strategy. I was hoping for some way to get the army to split.

Comment: I've never seen the AI split a stack, even when suffering attrition. :/

Comment: These mercenaries of yours, do they happen to be a holy order? Because they don't fight people of the same faith, even if they're stacked with normal troops. What I'm trying to say, is that your effective army might be considerably weaker than 10K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just chain assassinate the bastard.. put your spy master around his army and cross your finger.. If the claimant is dead then the war is over without you could rise your country levies.

Answer (score 3):

Well you've already covered mercenaries, terrain and morale. Things you haven't mentioned:

- Ensure you have the best commanders for your army. High martial skill is good, but don't forget modifiers from combat traits.
- Let the enemy army siege your holdings and suffer losses and attrition before you engage them. Ensure your forces don't suffer attrition by splitting them across several nearby holdings.
- It's possible to get lucky and kill/imprison enemy generals in battle. This can give you an advantage, but cannot be relied upon.
- Don't forget about allies. Check you don't have any in-laws in charge of armies who might be willing to help out.

If all else fails, remember that CK2 is a long game and losses can be recovered so long as your dynasty survives. You may want to consider surrendering some holdings to the enemy to secure peace, in order to crush them later. Some of my most satisfying experiences have come from suffering losses or bad fortune, carrying on anyway and coming back stronger later on.

Good luck!

Comment: Good points, all. Don't forget to check for unwed relatives who can be turned into quick alliances. Also, if the invader is a different religion or heretic, try calling out the holy orders.